# "Allow Sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer Mode" is missing in Edge Version 90

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to use EDGE to browse some legacy apps using IE mode, but this setting in Default Browser Settings is missing in EDGE browser settings. How do i enable this setting? its not greyed out, its missing all together.

Things i've tried so far,

1. Installed all Windows 10 Updates.
2. Downloaded and configured EDGE policy templates.
3. Enabled "Configure Internet explorer Integration" in policies

Still the setting is not available in Edge, kindly advice on what could be done, thanks

Comment: Probably Internet Explorer is still somewhere in the file system. `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe` or `Program Files (x86)`. If it is, as an alternative open the legacy web app directly from there.

Comment: IE is still there, but i'm trying to use the IE mode which should be there in EDGE settings

Comment: **Still the setting is not available in Edge** - Have you considered that it may simply not exist in Edge?

Comment: Get rid of your legacy apps. Microsoft is phasing out IE step by step. You're just delaying the inevitable.